# Finding the latest date of 2 date columns in SQL

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble finding a solution to the following SQL query:

I have a table that contains 2 date columns: `PurchaseDate` and `RefundDate`

I have a `StartDate` and `EndDate` that defines the date range for the query.

I want to restrict the query by either the `PurchaseDate` OR the `RefundDate` whichever is **earliest**. Also either date can be null.

So if PurchaseDate is 18.Nov.2013 and RefundDate is 03.Dec.2013 then I want to use `PurchaseDate` in the `where` clause to restrict the result set within the `startDate` and `EndDate`

Another example, is if PurchaseDate is 01.Aug.2013 and RefundDate is 19.May.2013 then I would want to use RefundDate in the where clause.

This is what I've got so far but it's not correct, I need to select whichever is the earliest of the 2 dates to restrict the where clause:

```
SELECT OrderID, AddressID, PurchaseDate, RefundDate
FROM
Orders
WHERE
(PurchaseDate IS NOT NULL AND PurchaseDate >= @queryStartDate 
   AND  PurchaseDate <= @queryEndDate) OR
 (RefundDate IS NOT NULL AND RefundDate >= @queryStartDate 
       AND  RefundDate <= @queryEndDate)
```

I thought about using `COALESCE` but this won't work as it will just pick the first date that is non-null rather than the earliest.

I think I'm going to have to do two queries and union them but it feels like there is a better way and I can do it with one query and some clever magic in the where clause....

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry - SQLServer 2012 - just added a tag for it

Comment: I'd like to know why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using additional clauses in the logic:

```
SELECT OrderID, AddressID, PurchaseDate, RefundDate
FROM Orders o
WHERE (PurchaseDate IS NOT NULL and
       PurchaseDate <= coalesce(RefundDate, PurchaseDate) and
       PurchaseDate between @queryStartDate AND @queryEndDate
      ) or
      (RefundDate IS NOT NULL and
       RefundDate <= coalesce(PurchaseDate, RefundDate and
       RefundDate between @queryStartDate AND @queryEndDate
      );
```

If you have indexes on the columns, the `union` method could be faster (even with the duplicate elimination).

Answer (score 0):

`case` is your friend...  Instead of a coalesce, write

```
 case when PurchaseDate < RefundDate 
       then PurchaseDate else RefundDate end
```

So, your query becomes:

```
 SELECT OrderID, AddressID, PurchaseDate, RefundDate
 FROM Orders
 WHERE case when PurchaseDate < RefundDate 
            then PurchaseDate else RefundDate end 
       Between @queryStartDate And @queryEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as using a least function.

```
SELECT OrderID, AddressID, PurchaseDate, RefundDate
FROM Orders
WHERE least( PurchaseDate , RefundDate ) Between @queryStartDate And @queryEndDate
```

Comment: The idea could be good, but if one of them is null you are in trouble.

Comment: Perhaps `COALESCE` the dates within the `least`.

Comment: Sorry, I originally didn't specify the DBMS (SQL Server2012). I think LEAST is Oracle only isn't it?